# Show that there exist a positive integer $n$ in the interval $(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a>0$ and $b>0$ two real numbers such that $b>a+1$. Show that there exist a positive integer $n$ in the interval $(a,b)$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Arthur: Just some numerical examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume no integer between $a$ and $b$.

Consider a non-integer $x$ between $a$ and $b$. $\lceil x \rceil \geq b$, $\lfloor x \rfloor \leq a$ $\implies \lceil x \rceil - \lfloor x \rfloor \geq b - a > 1$ which is not possible

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the largest nonnegative integer less than or equal to $a$. Then $n\leq a<n+1$. Since $n+1-a\leq n+1-n= 1$ we have that $0<n+1-a<b-a$, so $a< n+1<b$, and we are done.